Debian as iSCSI initiator on boot
I have a Debian GNU/Linux 12 virtual machine (amd64) that should mount this iSCSI volume on boot.
Following this guide the iscsiadm command did everything it was supposed to do and I was able to manually mount the volume. However the iscsiadm  --mode node  --targetname "..." --portal "...:3260" command placed the initiator configuration files under /var/lib/iscsi/... and not under /etc/iscsi. I'm not sure that's the problem, but on reboot the server did not initiate the iSCSI connection and it did not mount the volume.
I then copied /var/lib/iscsi/* to /etc/iscsi/ and it started working on boot too. For a while. Today it stopped after a reboot without any obvious reason (not obvious to me at least).
Using apt I noticed there was an open-iscsi update available from sid (version 2.1.10-2 while I had 2.1.10-1 installed) and I tried to install that, which resumed my iSCSI connection without editing anything. However the changelog for that new version states it only adds support for the riscv64 arch, which I do not have.
Upon inspecting the situation, I see that the /var/lib/iscsi/nodes directory was touched during the package upgrade (I don't understand why), while the /etc/iscsi/nodes directory was not (I do understand why). However the contents of both directories were still the same (rsync -rcnv /var/lib/iscsi/nodes/ /etc/iscsi/nodes/ showed nothing to sync).
Rebooting the server once again, the iSCSI connection did resume correctly, but I'm not sure I can trust this situation. Looking for errors around the time it failed before, using journalctl | grep -i iscsi, does not bring up any error messages except:
nov 27 10:46:32 adh systemd[1]: iscsid.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/iscsid.pid: Invalid argument
which is followed by a correct initiator startup anyway (at least from the logs point of view, but in reality it was not working).
Is manually copying the contents of /var/lib/iscsi directory under /etc/iscsi/ the correct, though undocumented, way to go? Or is there anything else/different to do in order to make the system reliably create the iSCSI device on boot?

this looks like a home and end-user computing questions to me, due it looks really like a test setup

It's a test setup in that it's not production ready yet, but it's a server I'm configuring for a customer. The iSCSI volume is going to hold the database and files of a self hosted GitLab instance, for the record. That being said, even if it were a home server, I would hardly imagine end users configuring an iSCSI initiator, and I believe it would be a server administration question anyway. However if the mod feels this question belongs to superuser, no problem, just move it, thanks.
